# How to allow User to login only once at a time?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have used Spring Security Core plugin in my grails application, and I want to add the functionality:

When a user is already logged in, user will not be allowed to use same `userName` and `password` to login again using a different browser or a different machine altogether.

I think it should be somewhere in the spring security core but not sure.

Comment: Why down voting? because of the title or something, if you are not interested, single sign on -> login from one place only, this is what I meant.
so if you have something to tell then pl let me know otherwise ...
:)

Comment: See http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#concurrent-sessions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done using some configuration settings:

on the **config.groovy**, add this line:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.useHttpSessionEventPublisher = true
```

On the **bootstrap.groovy**:

import these two packages:

```
    import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SecurityFilterPosition
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
```

Then few dependency injections:

```
    def authenticationManager
def concurrentSessionController
def securityContextPersistenceFilter
def authenticationProcessingFilter
def concurrentSessionControlStrategy
```

then register concurrency filter inside init(In Bootstrap):

```
    authenticationProcessingFilter.sessionAuthenticationStrategy = concurrentSessionControlStrategy

SpringSecurityUtils.clientRegisterFilter('concurrencyFilter', SecurityFilterPosition.CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER)
```

and at the end in the **resources.groovy**:

import few packages:

```
    import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy
import org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistry;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy
```

then inside beans add:

```
 sessionRegistry(SessionRegistryImpl)

  concurrencyFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter) {

    sessionRegistry = sessionRegistry
    logoutHandlers = [ref("rememberMeServices"), ref("securityContextLogoutHandler")]
    expiredUrl='/login/concurrentSession'
  }

  concurrentSessionControlStrategy(ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy, sessionRegistry) {
    alwaysCreateSession = true
    exceptionIfMaximumExceeded = true
    maximumSessions = 1
  }
```

and done, now user can login only from one place.

I didn't tried it with the rememberMe option.

Comment: hi.. this is for grails 2,,,how about for grails 3?
i see concurrentSessionControlStrategy already deprecated..
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-deprecations-web-cscs

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [Persistent Logins and Remember-Me Cookie](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#9.3%20Remember-Me%20Cookie). The idea is to persist the remember-me token in database and check whether a cookie is present in the database or not in subsequent login attempts. If a cookie is present then disallow the login.

This has to work in conjunction with the key `rememberMe.tokenValiditySeconds` so that the token expires and is purged from the database.

You would get more insight and throw some light to this scenario if you look at

- [How to Create Persistent Token](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/ref/Scripts/s2-create-persistent-token.html)
- [Best Practices in Persistent Login](http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice)
- [Remember-Me in Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html)